# java loop and add values to a map

Tags: java, list, dictionary, hashmap

New to using map and was wondering how to add values and loop thur it to retrieve the values.  Below is my code:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

for ( int i = 0, m = 1; i < visualcategory.size(); i = i+2, m = m+2) {
    String categoryName = visualcategory.get(m);
    map.put(categoryName , null);
}
```

for which i will be having this which is im assuming is correct even with the null

```
MAP {5=null, 11=null, 15=null, 24=null, 96=null, 98=null}
```

Its currently null as the next process (below) will fill up that list as it loops thru a for condition unless it can be done to add the categoryName and the List values at the same time?

Now, i need to loop and add a list from each string/map

```
String value1 = value;
String value2 = value;

for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    map.put(value1, entry.getValue());  --> doesn't work
    map.put(value2, entry.getValue());  --> doesn't work
}
```

I need something like this

```
MAP {5=[value1,value2,etc], 11=[value1,value2,etc], .......
```

Problem is, it doesn't work I can't seem to add inside the List. I need help on how to add values from a map > and loop thru to it?

Comment: The map contains `null` as values and no list, why not start there?

Comment: Do you want to add map values to List ?

Comment: Can you modify `MAP {5=null, 11=null, 15=null, 24=null, 96=null, 98=null}` with your example values instead of `null`? It is very confusing.. as you are expecting `MAP {5=[value1,value2,etc], 11=[value1,value2,etc], .......` and not null values..

Comment: Its currently null as the next process (below) will fill up that list as it loops thru a for condition unless it can be done to add the categoryName and the List values at the same time?

Comment: Have a look at Guava's [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Iterator insted of EntrySet

```
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
    Iterator itr=map.keySet().iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        String key =  itr.next().toString();
        String value=map.get(key).toString();
        System.out.println(key+"="+value);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
anotherMap.forEach((k, v) -> myMap.put(k.toString(), v.toString()));
```

Source: [Looping Through a Map in Java](http://codeflex.co/looping-through-a-map-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

When you create your map, instead of filling it with `null`s, fill it with empty `List`s:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

for ( int i = 0, m = 1; i < visualcategory.size(); i = i+2, m = m+2) {
    String categoryName = visualcategory.get(m);
    map.put(categoryName , new ArrayList<String>());
}
```

Now, when you're ready to populate the values, you can do:

```
String value1 = value;
String value2 = value;

for (List<String> list : map.values()) {
    list.add(value1);
    list.add(value2);
}
```

If you have the values when you're creating the map, you make it simpler:

```
String value1 = value;
String value2 = value;

Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

for ( int i = 0, m = 1; i < visualcategory.size(); i = i+2, m = m+2) {
    String categoryName = visualcategory.get(m);
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    values.add(value1);
    values.add(value2);
    map.put(categoryName, values);
}
```